# How to replace text with links using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I do to take out texts from a html usng Jquery:

```
$(".text").each(function(){

        var texts = items[textCount]['data']['title'];
        $(this).text(texts);
         textCount = textCount + 1;
      });
```

My problem if I want the texts to be a url, then it doesn't show up as link but also a string added to the texts variable. How do I show a link? How can add it as a href to the texts?

Output should be something like this:

Text + url

and not text being linked as url: `"<a href=\""+link+"\">"+texts+"</a>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.attr()` function like this.

```
$(this).attr("href", "your link");
```

But this will only work, if you have an anchor tag if not you can create an anchor tag on the fly.

```
$(this).html("<a href=\""+link+"\">"+texts+"</a>");
```

Comment: This creates a link of a text. I wanted something like this: texts + link and not linking of the text.

Comment: Update your question with the required HTML output.

Comment: Have updated it a bit. Not sure if that's exactly what you want.

Comment: Figured it out myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can make each element with class=text a link like this which assumes you have some kind of element that you are going to wrap with a hyperlink.  I'm not 100% sure this is what you are looking for.

```
$('.text').wrap('<a href="http://yourlinkhere.com"></a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do. Note:- this is more efficient than attr() as you are directly dealing with the object property.

```
this.href="yoururl"
```

You do not have to go through the followng jquery code which get called during attr inorder to just set the href attribute.

**Jquery attr function**

```
attr: function( elem, name, value, pass ) {
        var nType = elem.nodeType;

        // don't get/set attributes on text, comment and attribute nodes
        if ( !elem || nType === 3 || nType === 8 || nType === 2 ) {
            return undefined;
        }

        if ( pass && name in jQuery.attrFn ) {
            return jQuery( elem )[ name ]( value );
        }

        // Fallback to prop when attributes are not supported
        if ( !("getAttribute" in elem) ) {
            return jQuery.prop( elem, name, value );
        }

        var ret, hooks,
            notxml = nType !== 1 || !jQuery.isXMLDoc( elem );

        // Normalize the name if needed
        if ( notxml ) {
            name = jQuery.attrFix[ name ] || name;

            hooks = jQuery.attrHooks[ name ];

            if ( !hooks ) {
                // Use boolHook for boolean attributes
                if ( rboolean.test( name ) ) {
                    hooks = boolHook;

                // Use nodeHook if available( IE6/7 )
                } else if ( nodeHook ) {
                    hooks = nodeHook;
                }
            }
        }

        if ( value !== undefined ) {

            if ( value === null ) {
                jQuery.removeAttr( elem, name );
                return undefined;

            } else if ( hooks && "set" in hooks && notxml && (ret = hooks.set( elem, value, name )) !== undefined ) {
                return ret;

            } else {
                elem.setAttribute( name, "" + value );
                return value;
            }

        } else if ( hooks && "get" in hooks && notxml && (ret = hooks.get( elem, name )) !== null ) {
            return ret;

        } else {

            ret = elem.getAttribute( name );

            // Non-existent attributes return null, we normalize to undefined
            return ret === null ?
                undefined :
                ret;
        }
    },
```

Comment: But you are assuming that the attr exists.

Comment: @Hick Its just dealing as a javascript object. If href doesn't exist this will add href property. was this your question? And also for href attribute evenif you dont mention it in the html tag, the object will have href attribute always. You can check it yourself and please correct me if i am wrong...